# USB PCIe with RPi 4 for Graphics Cards?

Tags: pi-4, pci

So I found these [USB PCIe adaptors on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B076KLJR2Y) for a decent price. Given the new USB 3 capabilities of the RPi 4, would it be possible to use these to connect an older (not modern) graphics card like an Nvidea GF FX5200?

My interest is more in offloading some of the heavy graphics and processing from the main GPU, which I believe would smooth performance and reduce thermal load from the main board, allowing you to run slightly newer games or heavier applications without as many issues.

Thoughts?

Comment: There's a huge difference between USB 3 and PCIe. Modern PCs may support PCIe over a USB Type-C connector with ThunderBolt 3 support, but it's a different protocol. As far as I know, no RPi supports PCIe or ThunderBolt in general over USB.

Comment: I heard that CM3 (Compute Module 3) uses PCIe. So should be CM4: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=98&t=243395&sid=1fc1e09460526685b1328c27745e75c3